# Pair function that generate unique value for a given number of integers

Tags: math, mapping, unique

I have various sets of integers each set can have from 2 to >10 integers with values between 0 and 500ish (variable). I would like to pair them into a unique number. 
I have explored the Cantor pairing function, but I would have to combine two numbers at a time and for longer groups of number it would soon result in very large numbers.

For example:
set 1: [1,12,65,4] will be mapped to a unique value different for the value representing set 2: [1,12,65,2].

Also, another nice to have requirement would be that sets [1,4,78,5] and [1,4,78,10] would be close to each other when represented by a unique number.

Is this possible mathematically?

Comment: 10 numbers with 500 possible values gives about 1 octillion sequences (assuming that order matters). That requires about 90 bits with perfect packing. Is that in the range that you imagine? Or do you need something in the 32 / 64 bit range?

Comment: order doesn't matter actually, good point. And yeah I need that number to be one of the axis of a graph, so that sets with common integers are closer to each other. So it cannot get to large... I should have said this before probably. Thanks !

Comment: That's still about 68 bits worth of different combinations. If you really need uniqueness and compactness, that seems hard to achieve. A mapping to a space-filling curve (e.g. [Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) or [Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve)) might be other ways to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want an injective function R^n -> R. Yes, this is definitely possible.

The easiest solution would be just to string the digits together. For example, for [1,12,65,4] each digit can be represented as [001,012,065,004] and you could map this to 1012065004. This also has the property that it is close to [1,12,65,2] -> 1012065002.

Another solution is to "interweave" the digits. For example, if you have [abc,def] -> adbecf. So for [1,12,65,4] -> [001,012,065,004] -> '000001601254' -> 1601254. This results in smaller values.

Once you have this injective function, you can compose it with another injective function R -> R (e.g. f(x) = log x) to make the values not too large for your application.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought of the stringing of the digits and taking the log, but interweaving idea is simply genius. I'll try this approach thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think cantor tuple function could be a solution. Just before that sort the numbers of the set, and then pass to the [cantor tuple function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

In this way, you will get a unique result for each set, and somehow, it could satisfy the nice requirement (Not the best, but could be as a solution).

[image]